# seiyria/bootstrap-slider getValue() not working

Tags: slider, range, getvalue, bootstrap-slider

I've looked through all the answers on this topic, but for some reason I can't get it to work.
I've set up a slider with the following markup:

```
<input data-slider-id="Xslide" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step=".5" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-reversed="true"></input>
```

What I want first of all is to console.log its numerical value. I've tried playing with the `type` to `number` or `text` but that didn't work. I tried as per the example on GitHub:

```
var mySlider = $("Xslide").slider();
var value = mySlider.slider('getValue');
console.log(value);
```

but that produced the error `$(...).getValue is not a function`

I tried writing `$('#Xslide').data('slider').getValue()` but that produced the error `$(...).data(...) is undefined`.

I tried solutions offered on the example page like

```
$('#Xslide').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        console.log('Current value: ' + value);
    }
});
```

but that just doesn't show anything in the console at all..

I've included the following js and css files:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Not sure why it isn't working... perhaps it's something about the input element `id` or the `type`, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, I don't really know how to dd a jsfiddle that includes the js and css files since they are local on my computer...

Comment: In any case so far I've solved it using:

var Xslide = new Slider('#Xslide');

Xslide.on('slideStop', function (value) {
  document.getElementById('xval').innerHTML = value;
})

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case so far I've solved it using:

```
var Xslide = new Slider('#Xslide'); 

Xslide.on('slideStop', function (value) { document.getElementById('xval').innerHTML = value; 
})
```

Thanks!