# How to capture the value onChange in Bootstrap-Slider plugin

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-slider

I cannot figure out how to capture the change in value on the bootstrap-slider plugin.

Read the documentation. Tried many, many things.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language_spanhish">Spanish</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="language_spanish" type="text" data-provide="slider"
      data-slider-ticks="[0, 1, 2]"
      data-slider-min="0"
      data-slider-max="2"
      data-slider-step="1"
      data-slider-value="0"
      data-slider-tooltip="show"
      onchange="alert('you changed it')"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried (no success):

```
    document.getElementById("#language_spanish").getAttribute("data-slider-value");
        var getIt = $('#language_spanish').data('slider').getValue();
        alert(getIt);
spanish.on("slide", function(slideEvt) { console.log(slider.getValue() ); alert(slideEvt.value); });
        $('#language_spanish').slider().on('slide', function(ev){ alert("I changed it") });
```

Just looking for anyone out there that has successfully captured the change in value on the slider. Please post back if the plugin does not support the ability to capture the change in value.

One console log error I get from some of the attempts is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky solved it here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825650/seiyria-bootstrap-slider-getvalue-not-working !!! Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
$('#language_spanish').on('input', function(ev){ alert("I changed it") });
```

For `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` You can bypass jQuery (not tested):

```
var slider = document.getElementById("language_spanish")
console.log("init : " + slider.value)
slider.addEventListener('input', function(e){ alert("I changed it " + e.currentTarget.value + " === " + input.value) });
```

Comment: nope...got that `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error again @Arthur.

Comment: will try next suggestion

Comment: Take care, you include the "#" on getElementById. I re-update my answer to remove it

Comment: got this `Uncaught TypeError: slider.on is not a function` @Arthur

Comment: I am having a tough time tracking with you @Arthur. you don't have semi-colons in your script for line breaks and I am putting them in on my side.

Comment: sorry `on` is a jquery function. Use `addEventListerner` instead

Comment: Well might be getting closer @Arthur. No errors but no alerts of console logs either...

Comment: No luck @Arthur. `var slider = document.getElementById("language_spanish");' .
             '  slider.addEventListener('input', function(e){ alert("I changed it") });`

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires jquery.

The slider comes with it's own event handlers, which don't include input, but do include "change". https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

```
$("#language_spanish").on("change", function(){
console.log("Changed");
});
```

If you want to get the new value of the slider, then.

```
$("#language_spanish").on("change", function(event){
console.log("Changed to ", event.value.newValue);
});
```